# Error module not find in turning a py file to an exe file

Tags: python, file, tkinter, exe, customtkinter

I used the customtkinter module to make a pomodoro timer and I wanted to turn the file to an exe file.
Here is the error that I get when I tried to launch the exe file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import customtkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'customtkinter'
```

when I run the py file on PyCharm, I get no error and the pomodoro timer is working.
I used pyinstaller to convert it and firstly I used the command:
`pyinstaller --onefile main.py`
which gave me this error
secondly I gave it a try without the `--onefile` and this time the exe file just open and close
I checked to see in the venv directory and I saw that there is the customtkinter package in the site-package directory

I tried a method where I create a new python file where we write:

```py
from PyInstaller.utils.hook import collect_submodules
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('win10toast')
```

I tried with the command `pyinstaller --onefile --path="The path to the module"`
I tried the command `pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import customtkinter main.py`

and nothing work do you have an idea to resolve this bug?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? It states you have to add the directory with the `--add-data` command. [Here](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/packaging). Did you do that? It also states not to use the `--onefile` option

Comment: `pyinstaller --onefile main.py` using `PyInstaller` 6.3.0, `customtkinter` 5.2.1 and `Python` 3.12.1 in Windows 11, the generated executable works fine.

Comment: I checked the documentation i tried the command
<code> pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --add-data "<CustomTkinter Location>/customtkinter;customtkinter/"  "<Path to Python Script>" <code>

Answer (score -1):

I attempted to duplicate your error but wasn't able to. However, from your question its possible your customtkinter module is the problem. Try running this:

`pip uninstall customtkinter`

`pip install --upgrade pip`

`pip install customtkinter`

Comment: If a question doesn't give you enough information to replicate the problem so answers can be tested, that's a reason to vote to close the question (as lacking a [mre]), not to add an untested and uncertain answer.